# How to install xsendfile for httpd 2.4 on amazon linux ami?

Tags: amazon-web-services, x-sendfile, apache2.4

How to install xsendfile for httpd 2.4 on amazon linux ami? Default package repositories from amazon and epel do not have a package for httpd 2.4, only for httpd 2.2. I would prefer not to compile the module if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a quick Yum/apt-get style install for X-sendfile for Apache24 on an EC2 instance at the time of writing this answer, however compiling and installing the module your self is super easy:

## Prepwork

Download  ***mod_xsendfile.c*** from *download section* the link below

```
https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/
```

Install GCC for compiling

```
sudo yum install gcc
```

We need httpd24-devel for apxs

```
sudo yum install httpd24-devel.x86_64
```

### Compiling and installation

```
sudo apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c
```

Edit your http.conf add

```
<IfModule mod_xsendfile.c>
  XSendFile on
  XSendFilePath /home/path/to/private/files/to/serve/
</IfModule>
```

Restart Apache24

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

**Done !**

Check your phpinfo or apache_modules() to confirm all good and modify settings to your liking.
Enjoy efficient downloads :)